# Audio device input name truncated

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2005, audio-recording

I'm trying to get the audio input device name with the code bellow:

```
WAVEINCAPS woc;
unsigned long iNumDevs = waveInGetNumDevs(); 
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < iNumDevs; i++) 
{ 
    if (!waveInGetDevCaps(i, &woc, sizeof(WAVEINCAPS))) 
    {
        devices.push_back(woc.szPname);
    } 
}
```

When i look in `devices`, there are all input devices names, but all names are truncated in 32 characters.

How can I get the complete name?

Answer (score 0):

The `szPname` member of the `WAVEINCAPS` structure is limited to `MAXPNAMELEN` characters, which is defined as 32.

You could try enumerating using another technology that might not have this limitation, for example using [DirectSound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).